# javax authenticator refer to same email address

Tags: java, authentication, caching, jakarta-mail

Here is the code I use to create session to send email:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");
logger.trace("1. emailFromAddress: " + emailFromAddress);
session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
     logger.trace("2. emailFromAddress + " pass: " + password);
     return new PasswordAuthentication(emailFromAddress, password);
    }
});
```

Then i try to input emailFromAddress = "abc@yahoo.com" and its password.
I can authenticate the address and send email successfully, and

```
1. emailFromAddress: abc@yahoo.com
2. emailFromAddress: abc@yahoo.com pass: *****
```

I try to send from different emailFromAddress = "xyz@gmail.com" --> this time it failed to send and the log printout as:

```
1. emailFromAddress: xyz@gmail.com --> WHICH IS CORRECT
2. emailFromAddress: abc@yahoo.com pass: ***** --> WHICH STILL REFER TO THE OLD ACCOUNT
```

is there any cache of the session authenticator?

Answer (score 0):

There is *some kind* of cache: you've created the `Authenticator` once in your example, and set it on the default session. Since that object lives forever (or at least until your JVM terminates) it will behave the same way at every invocation.

Maybe you could use the [`getDefaultUserName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Authenticator.html#getDefaultUserName%28%29) from `Authenticator` to supply the user name?

Another option might be to re-configure a new `Authenticator` with every mail that you send. Thus you can supply the correct username on every attempt.

Comment: seems like getDefaultInstance() return the defaultSession once it has been setup, regardless your Authenticator is updated. so I change to getInstance() and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

As java-doc:

`getDefaultInstance` Get the default Session object. If a default has not yet been setup, a new Session object is created and installed as the default.

`getInstance` Get a new Session object.
So, a new session object is created, regardless of whether one already exists.

so what do the trick is changing to `getInstance()`.